# Printing a char* in C++

Tags: c++, printing, pointers, char

I'm writing a simple program. There is only one class in it. There is a private member 'char * number' and two function (there will be more, but first these should work correctly :) ).

The first one should copy the 'source' into 'number' variable (and I suppose somewhere here is the problem):

```
LongNumber::LongNumber(const char * source ){
        int digits = strlen(source);

        char* number = new char[digits+1];
        strcpy( number, source );
        //  cout<<number<<endl; - if the line is uncommented,
        //  the output is correct and there isn't a problem

}
```

And a print function:

```
void LongNumber::print(){
    cout<<number<<endl;
    // when I try to print with the same line of code here..it crashes
}
```

Sure, I'm missing something...but what?

(As this is my first post...do you think the tags are corrected..how would you tagged the post?)

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `LongNumber` constructor you declare a new local variable named `number` and initialize it with a new `char` array:

```
char* number = new char[digits+1];
```

Instead you should leave out the `char*`, so that it doesn't look like a new variable declaration and uses the object member variable:

```
number = new char[digits+1];
```

With the current code, the member variable `number` never gets initialized and using it later in `print` leads to an error.

Answer (score 6):

Your number char* array would be out of scope when it exits the constructor. When you reach the print(), since the program no longer has access to the memory that *number is originally pointing to, it would crash (i.e. segmentation fault). To solve this problem do this instead:

```
class LongNumber
{
     char *number;
     LongNumber(const char *source);
     ~LongNumber();
     void print();
};

LongNumber::LongNumber(const char * source ){
        int digits = strlen(source);

        number = new char[digits+1];
        strcpy( number, source );    
}

void LongNumber::print(){
    cout<<number<<endl;
}
```

Don't forget to do the following:

```
LongNumber::~LongNumber()
{
    delete [] number;    // to avoid memory leaks
}
```

I would also highly recommend using STL::string rather than using char* for your *number variable, as you won't have to deal with memory management overhead yourself, and copying the string would be easier too.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your constructor:

```
LongNumber::LongNumber(const char * source )
{
  ...
  // you are declaring a new local variable called `number` here
  char* number = new char[digits+1];
  strcpy( number, source );
  ...
}
```

You are not copying into the class member variable called `number`, you are declaring a new local variable in the body of the constructor and using that. The class member variable is unused, and probably is undefined. For a pointer member, this means the value could be any invalid value - then when you call print:

```
void LongNumber::print()
{
  cout<<number<<endl;
  // when I try to print with the same line of code here..it crashes
}
```

The `number` you are using here, is the class member variable, which as we said is undefined. The call to `cout` will then crash since it tries to use that invalid pointer.

The fix is to make the constructor use the correct class member variable:

```
LongNumber::LongNumber(const char * source )
{
  ...
  // use the class member variable `number` here
  number = new char[digits+1];
  strcpy( number, source );
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your declaring number as a local variable. If you want to be able to call it again in another function, you have to declare it in the class definition... like so:

```
class LongNumber{
public:
        int digits;
        char* number;
        LongNumber(const char * source );
        void print();
}

LongNumber::LongNumber(const char * source ){
        digits = strlen(source);
        number = new char[digits+1];
        strcpy( number, source );
        //  cout<<number<<endl; - if the line is uncommented,
        //  the output is correct and there isn't a problem
}

void LongNumber::print(){
    cout<<number<<endl;
    // when I try to print with the same line of code here..it crashes
}
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: depends on how much in depth people are as well as other suggestions that could make the code even easier to manage